# Set a callback for MediaPlayer to get called after X seconds

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I got a MediaPlayer Object and after, lets say, 5 seconds of the songs time a callback should get called.

How is it possible to archive that with the MediaPlayer?

Or is it necessary to create a wrapper, start a new Thread, wait in that Thread for 5 seconds and call the callback function?

Comment: If you're really serious about getting help, paste the codes you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer doesn't have any such thing but one way to accomplish this is with `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`.  That will execute a Runnable after a specific delay.
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Another option is `Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)`.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long)

Answer (score 1):

Handler is something you are looking for since media player does not have any api for this.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 2000ms
    playMusic()
  }
}, 2000);
```